# Pihole gives an Conection refused error on my synology nas

Tags: synology, pihole

On my [synology](https://foxly.de/article/3-pi-hole-auf-einer-synology-nas-installieren/) nas I installed Pihole using this toutorial:
https://foxly.de/article/3-pi-hole-auf-einer-synology-nas-installieren/ (german)

I did all steps and after I tryed to open the site it gives me the Contection Refused Error

I tried reinstalling it but it didnt work.

I am new to this stuff can somebody help me?